# FirebaseUI install issue (iOS-Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebaseui

I've installed Firebase and am trying to install FirebaseUI, but when I try to 'import FirebaseUI', I get error: 'No such module FirebaseUI'

I've tried all three installation methods: CocoaPods, copying FirebaseUI.xcodeproj into my project and downloading from the release page.

I must be missing a step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you should open he Podfile and uncomment the #use_frameworks

Just remove the hash in front of it . Then type pod update and that should fix it.

Comment: @MichaelKaminowitz can also try cleaning the project. Project -> Clean

Comment: Sadly, this didn't fix the issue. Thank you though.

Comment: @MichaelKaminowitz I just faced this now...updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are opening the .workspace file that is created when you install the pod's rather than the normal .xcode file.